# After upgrading to Angular 5 my project won't build

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

After upgrading to Angular 5, my project won't build.  I am using Visual Studio 2017 15.4.3 and am using SystemJs.  My typescript version is 2.4.2.

I get the following 8 errors:

```
Error Build:',' expected. node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\transfer_state.d.ts    line 34 oolumn 31
Error Build:Type parameter declaration expected. node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\transfer_state.d.ts 34  oolumn 33
Error Build:Expression expected. node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\transfer_state.d.ts line 34 oolumn 37
Error Build:')' expected. node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\transfer_state.d.ts    line 34 oolumn 42
Error Build:';' expected. node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\transfer_state.d.ts    line 34 oolumn 50
Error Build:Declaration or statement expected. node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\transfer_state.d.ts   34  oolumn 51
Error Build:':' expected. node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\transfer_state.d.ts    line 35      oolumn 10
Error Build:',' expected. node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\transfer_state.d.ts    line 35      oolumn 28
```

Below is my package.json file:

```
            {
              "name": "mic",
              "version": "0.0.0",
              "license": "MIT",
              "scripts": {
                "ng": "ng",
                "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
                "build": "webpack -p",
                "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
                "lint": "ng lint",
                "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
                "copy": "xcopy \"dist\" \"..\\Mic\\Scripts\\NgApp\" /i /s /r /y /c",
                "prepree2e": "npm start",
                "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet"
              },
              "private": true,
              "dependencies": {
                "@angular/animations": "^5.0.2",
                "@angular/common": "^5.0.2",
                "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.2",
                "@angular/core": "^5.0.2",
                "@angular/forms": "^5.0.2",
                "@angular/http": "^5.0.2",
                "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.2",
                "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.2",
                "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.2",
                "@angular/router": "^5.0.2",
                "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^1.1.1",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^1.4.0",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^1.3.0",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^1.2.3",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^1.0.5",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^1.6.1",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^1.3.3",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.3.0",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.0.5",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^1.3.0",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor": "^1.0.5",
                "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.1.1",
                "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.4.0",
                "@progress/kendo-file-saver": "^1.0.4",
                "@progress/kendo-popup-common": "^1.2.3",
                "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.44.0",
                "@telerik/kendo-intl": "^1.3.0",
                "angular2-notifications": "^0.9.6",
                "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
                "core-js": "^2.5.1",
                "intl": "^1.2.5",
                "libphonenumber-js": "^0.4.40",
                "rxjs": "5.5.2",
                "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
                "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
              },
              "devDependencies": {
                "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
                "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.2",
                "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
                "@types/node": "^6.0.92",
                "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
                "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
                "cldr-data": "^31.0.2",
                "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
                "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
                "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
                "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
                "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
                "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
                "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
                "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
                "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
                "jszip": "^3.1.3",
                "karma": "~1.4.1",
                "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
                "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
                "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
                "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
                "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
                "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
                "less-loader": "^4.0.2",
                "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
                "postcss-url": "^5.1.2",
                "protractor": "~5.1.0",
                "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
                "rollup": "^0.43.0",
                "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.0.2",
                "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0",
                "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^2.0.1",
                "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
                "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
                "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
                "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
                "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
                "systemjs": "^0.20.19",
                "systemjs-plugin-babel": "0.0.25",
                "systemjs-plugin-json": "^0.3.0",
                "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
                "tslib": "^1.6.1",
                "tslint": "~4.5.0",
                "typescript": "2.4.2",
                "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
                "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.2"
              }
            }
```

Below is my tsconfig.json

```
    {
      "compileOnSave": true,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "importHelpers": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "typeRoots": [
          "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
          "es7",
          "dom"
        ]
      },
      "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts",
        "node_modules",
        "dist",
        "../Scripts"
      ]
    }
```

Please help.  This is very frustrating.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to finally fix it.  What I did was remove the Typescript extension from Visual Studio (unchecking the TypeScript options from the "Get Tools and Features" menu AND also removing it from "Extensions and Updates) and then downloading and installing "TypeScript 2.6.1 for Visual Studio 2017".  I had tried just installing "TypeScript 2.6.1 for Visual Studio 2017" but that didn't work.  My problem was only resolved by first removing Typescript from Visual Studio 2017 as described above and THEN installing "TypeScript 2.6.1 for Visual Studio 2017".  Before trying any of this, I did remove the node_modules directory as suggested by Melchia but that didn't work on its own but perhaps doing this first was a necessary part of the fix, although I'm not sure.  If removing Typescript and then installing it doesn't work for you, you could try removing the node_modules directory and running npm install.  Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: I am unable to find TypeScript options from the "Get Tools and Features" menu. pl help me.

Comment: Hi Narayana,  In Visual Studio 2017, click on the Tools menu and the first option should be "Get Tools and Features".  This should open the Visual Studio setup.  Go to the "Individual Components" Tab and the Typescript options are in the "SDKs, libraries, and frameworks" section.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this packages.json:

```
{
              "name": "mic",
              "version": "0.0.0",
              "license": "MIT",
              "scripts": {
                "ng": "ng",
                "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
                "build": "webpack -p",
                "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
                "lint": "ng lint",
                "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
                "copy": "xcopy \"dist\" \"..\\Mic\\Scripts\\NgApp\" /i /s /r /y /c",
                "prepree2e": "npm start",
                "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet"
              },
              "private": true,
              "dependencies": {
                "@angular/animations": "5.0.0",    
                "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
                "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
                "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
                "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
                "@angular/http": "5.0.0",    
                "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
                "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
                "@angular/router": "5.0.0",               
                "@angular/platform-server": "5.0.0",
                "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^1.1.1",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^1.4.0",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^1.3.0",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^1.2.3",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^1.0.5",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^1.6.1",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^1.3.3",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.3.0",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.0.5",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^1.3.0",
                "@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor": "^1.0.5",
                "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.1.1",
                "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.4.0",
                "@progress/kendo-file-saver": "^1.0.4",
                "@progress/kendo-popup-common": "^1.2.3",
                "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.44.0",
                "@telerik/kendo-intl": "^1.3.0",
                "angular2-notifications": "^0.9.6",
                "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
                "core-js": "^2.5.1",
                "intl": "^1.2.5",
                "libphonenumber-js": "^0.4.40",
                "rxjs": "5.5.2",
                "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
                "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
              },
              "devDependencies": {
                "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
                "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.2",
                "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
                "@types/node": "^6.0.92",
                "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
                "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
                "cldr-data": "^31.0.2",
                "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
                "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
                "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
                "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
                "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
                "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
                "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
                "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
                "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
                "jszip": "^3.1.3",
                "karma": "~1.4.1",
                "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
                "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
                "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
                "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
                "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
                "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
                "less-loader": "^4.0.2",
                "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
                "postcss-url": "^5.1.2",
                "protractor": "~5.1.0",
                "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
                "rollup": "^0.43.0",
                "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.0.2",
                "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0",
                "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^2.0.1",
                "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
                "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
                "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
                "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
                "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
                "systemjs": "^0.20.19",
                "systemjs-plugin-babel": "0.0.25",
                "systemjs-plugin-json": "^0.3.0",
                "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
                "tslib": "^1.6.1",
                "tslint": "~4.5.0",
                "typescript": "2.6.1",
                "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
                "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.2"
              }
            }
```

delete node_modules folder & run **npm install**

Comment: Hi Melchia, Thanks for your answer.  I tried it but unfortunately it did not work.  Do you have any other suggestions?